# IC that allows two dc voltages to switch to one of them as output

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, mosfet, pic, switches

I am unable to find any IC that would allow me to have 2 DC inputs (5v/12v coming from the PC psu) and have one of them as output (being either 5v out or 12v out). **This is for power to a PC Fan that should, at the far end when using a 140mm case fan, would pull 4.2 to 6W. So around ~400mA...**

I figured that a DPST switch would work but I'm not quite sure that is what I need for this?

An illustration of what I am looking for the IC to do:
[image]

Being hooked to a microcontroller (PIC), I would be able to switch from the default voltage (that being 5vdc) to the 12vdc and, if needed, back to 5vdc.

Anyone know of an IC that would work like this for my needed purpose? It would also be nice if the IC had 4 outputs (2 inputs) so that I wouldn't have to have so many of them on my PCB. I will have 8 4pin connectors so that would be a total of 8 outputs that I would need.

So something like this?
[image]

Comment: How about an SPDT relay?

Comment: What current do you need? If it's low (mA or less) "analog switch". Otherwise "solid state relay". But you need a third DC voltage (usually a logic level) to control the switch.

Comment: Also, you don't need 4 outputs. You only need two outputs to switch the 5 / 12 V lines. The GNDs of the power supplies can be tied together..

Comment: "I figured that a DPST switch would work" - think again.

Comment: @m.Alin i need each of the 8 4pin connectors to have different voltage at times.

Comment: This question is unanswerable as you do not specify how much current you want to switch. Until you specify that current the safe option is to recommend relays.

Comment: Are you trying to switch between two power voltages, or are these just signals?  How much current will be drawn from the output?

Comment: Updated my OP for you all.

Comment: For a PC fan the standard approach is feeding it 12V and controlling the speed by PWM, either as a 25 kHz signal through a dedicated PWM connection (for so-called PWM fans), or by PWM-ing the power (for so-called DC fans).

Comment: Do you need it dynamically controllable - if it is only whether a 5V or 12V fans is installed then you could statically configure it with a header to allow the user to set the required voltage.

Comment: @KevinWhite That's too boring :) I want to switch the voltage via software (the microcontroller).

Comment: what is the max voltage you can supply greater than 12, how about using a variable power supply? that is powering the fan, which is controlled by micro controller to supply 5V/12V

Answer (score 1):

A relay may be the simple answer to your need. You wire your output to the "common" terminal and then make it switch between 5V and 12V. Wire each DC input either to NC or NO taking into account which one will be used most of the time.

**EDIT**: if relays are not convenient for you, consider using analog switches like [these from TI](http://www.ti.com/lit/sg/slyb125d/slyb125d.pdf).

Comment: Would like a ic way of doing it instead of having 8 big relays on the board.

Comment: Then maybe analog switches will do (take a look at the edit in my answer) .

Comment: Analog switches can only be used in certain circumstances. It is unclear from the question if these can be used in this case.

Comment: I agree with you, @FakeMoustake. Maybe the OP could provide more info so we can advise him better?

Comment: Ive updated my OP @EnricBlanco

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a PIC, I would suggest something as simple as 1 FET or BJT darlington driving the fan at 12V, and a [PWM for the PIC output](https://electrosome.com/pwm-pic-microcontroller-mplab-xc8/).

This way you can make the PIC output any voltage from 0 to 12V with only 1 pin.

Maybe your PIC already has embedded PWM. If not, PWM is simple to implement, just set the output pin high for, say, 500us, then low for 700us, and keep doing this forever. This way  you will have a pulse of 1200us width with 41,7% duty cycle, which is equal to 5Vrms at 833,33Hz.

**More examples:**
**12**00us high, 0us low = **12**V
**7**00us high, 500us low = **7**V
**3**00us high, 800us low = **3**V

**Circuit should be something like this:**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fa6eBP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>